# Are aspose cells available in portlet/webapp?

Tags: java, portlet, aspose-cells

I'm writing a web that allow user upload excel file, the convert the content into MYSQL statement.

The code:

```
public void convertToSQL(ActionRequest actionRequest,ActionResponse actionResponse) throws Exception 
    {
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        try {
        conn = this.getDbConnection(conn);
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        UploadPortletRequest uploadPortletRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(actionRequest); 
        String uploadedTemplateId = uploadPortletRequest.getParameter("templateId");
        System.out.println("uploadedTemplateId:"+uploadedTemplateId);

        File uploadedFile = uploadPortletRequest.getFile("uploadedFile", true); 
        System.out.println("uploadedDocument:" + uploadedFile.getName());
        String test2="insert akpi_db.dbo.tpl_estimate_gdh (hosp) values ('testgetfile')";
        pstmt = conn.prepareCall(test2);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();

        Workbook wb1 = new Workbook(uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath());
        String test1="insert akpi_db.dbo.tpl_estimate_gdh (hosp) values ('testgetpath')";
        pstmt = conn.prepareCall(test1);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        int pageNum = wb1.getWorksheets().getCount();
        test1="insert akpi_db.dbo.tpl_estimate_gdh (hosp) values ('getpageNum')";
        pstmt = conn.prepareCall(test1);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        for (int i=0;i< pageNum;i++){
            Worksheet ws1 = wb1.getWorksheets().get(i);
            Cells cells1 = ws1.getCells();
            int row = getPrintAreaMaxRow(ws1);
            int col = getPrintAreaMaxColumn(ws1);
            final String as_at_date_id = "convert(varchar(8), getdate(), 112)";
            final String process_dtm = "getdate()";


            for (int j=6;j<row;j++){
                for (int k=0;k<col;k=k+2){
                    Cell fin_year_cell = cells1.get(1,1);
                    Cell hosp_cell = cells1.get(j,0);
                    String[] parts = fin_year_cell.getStringValue().split("/");
                    int fin_year = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
                    String hosp = hosp_cell.getStringValue().replaceAll("\\s+", "");


                    Cell gdh_places_cell = cells1.get(j,k);
                    Cell gdh_attns_cell = cells1.get(j,k+1);


                    String gdh_places = gdh_places_cell.getStringValue();
                    String gdh_attns = gdh_attns_cell.getStringValue();


                    Cell cal_cell = cells1.get(4,k);
                    String[] date = cal_cell.getStringValue().split("-"); //date[1] = cal_year
                    int cal_month = 0,fin_month=0;
                if (date[0] == "Jan"){
                        fin_month=10;
                        cal_month=1;
                }else if (date[0] == "Feb"){
                        fin_month=11;
                        cal_month=2;
                }else if (date[0] == "Mar"){
                        fin_month=12;
                        cal_month=3;
                }else if (date[0] == "Apr"){
                        fin_month=1;
                        cal_month=4;
                }else if (date[0] == "May"){
                        fin_month=2;
                        cal_month=5;
                }else if (date[0] == "Jun"){
                        fin_month=3;
                        cal_month=6;
                }else if (date[0] == "Jul"){
                        fin_month=4;
                        cal_month=7;
                }else if (date[0] == "Aug"){
                        fin_month=5;
                        cal_month=8;
                }else if (date[0] == "Sep"){
                        fin_month=6;
                        cal_month=9;
                }else if (date[0] == "Oct"){
                        fin_month=7;
                        cal_month=10;
                }else if (date[0] == "Nov"){
                        fin_month=8;
                        cal_month=11;
                }else if (date[0] == "Dec"){
                        fin_month=9;
                        cal_month=12;
                }

                   if ( cal_month!=0 && fin_month!=0){

                    String sql ="insert into akpi_db.dbo.tpl_estimate_gdh (hosp,cal_year,cal_month,fin_year,fin_month,gdh_place,gdh_attn,as_at_date_id,process_dtm)"+
                            "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                    String test="insert akpi_db.dbo.tpl_estimate_gdh (hosp) values ('testconvert')";
                    pstmt = conn.prepareCall(test);
/*                  pstmt.setString(1, hosp);
                    pstmt.setString(2, date[1]);
                    pstmt.setInt(3, cal_month);
                    pstmt.setInt(4, fin_year);
                    pstmt.setInt(5, fin_month);
                    pstmt.setString(6, gdh_places);
                    pstmt.setString(7, gdh_attns);
                    pstmt.setString(8, as_at_date_id);
                    pstmt.setString(9, process_dtm);*/

                    pstmt.executeUpdate();

                   }
            }
        }

        }
        pstmt.close();
        conn.commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
             if (conn != null) {
                 try {
                        conn.setAutoCommit(true);
                        conn.close();
                } catch(SQLException excep) {
                       System.out.println("Connection cannot be closed.");
                }
             }
         }

    }
```

But I found that my code not work, and after I try to debug. The error was occur at this line

```
int pageNum = wb1.getWorksheets().getCount();
```

The problem is, in the log file, it haven't throw any exception out. In the database for testing, it only insert "testgetfile" and "testgetpath"
"getpageNum" and "testconvert" have not insert to the db, so I guess the error occur on above sentences.

Even I try to upload multi page or single page excel to the web, both of them are not work

But what is this sentences wrong? the compiler and server doesn't give me any error exception.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share a sample demo application (runnable) with sample files. We will reproduce the problem and provide our feedback after analysis.

Note: I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.